# Google Maps shows blank(white) screen after app installation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

Google maps is not loading and always shows blank screen on my android app, but there is no error every time i build my project.

Here's my code:

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.smartmotor">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/smlogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDg_yZowxEhnWBXVEaLanuuPYhhlrJCrxM"/>

        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.user.smartmotor.IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My fragment_location.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.smartmotor.Fragment.LocatorFragment">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_loc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my LocatorFragment.java:

```
    package com.example.user.smartmotor.Fragment;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.user.smartmotor.GlobalValues;
import com.example.user.smartmotor.MainActivity;
import com.example.user.smartmotor.R;
import com.example.user.smartmotor.SmsSender;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class LocatorFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private static View view;
    private GoogleMap map;

    public LocatorFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment LocatorFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static LocatorFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        LocatorFragment fragment = new LocatorFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                GlobalValues.PrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locator, container, false);
            mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            final FloatingActionButton clickButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_loc);

            clickButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(prefs.contains("CurrentMobileNo")){
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                .setTitle("Smart Motor")
                                .setMessage("Location Request Success! Please wait for the update.")
                                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        //do things
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();

                        SmsSender.sendSMS(prefs.getString("CurrentMobileNo",""),"!@gps");
                    }else{
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                .setTitle("Smart Motor")
                                .setMessage("Cannot Request Location, Please set the mobile number in settings.")
                                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        //do things
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }



                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }

        ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                .setActionBarTitle("Locator");


        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
        map = googleMap;
        CameraUpdate center=
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(14.6717228,
                        121.0441268));
        CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);

        googleMap.moveCamera(center);
        googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(GlobalValues.currentLocation != null){
                    map.clear();
                    String currentLocation = GlobalValues.currentLocation;
                    String[] currentLocationSplit = currentLocation.split(",");
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(currentLocationSplit[0]);
                    Double lng = Double.parseDouble(currentLocationSplit[1]);

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);

                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title("Current Motor Location.");

                    map.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
                    GlobalValues.currentLocation = null;
                }


                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();

    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the google logo shown?

Comment: @Lal yes, Google logo appears in the lower-left of the screen and a button on the upper-right.

Comment: That means your api key is wrong...check it once more..